# Linker killed with Signal 9

Tags: travis-ci

While compiling ArangoDB often (but not always) the compile aborts with a KILL to the linker processes:
https://travis-ci.org/triAGENS/ArangoDB/builds/48323023
However, it doesn't happen always. Whats the best way to find out whats wrong? or any tips whats actually going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the `.travis.yml` for ArangoDB so it now uses gold instead of ld for linking.

gold will use far less system resources than ld, so the builds will currently not get killed during linking.

This is only a temporary solution as the root cause for Travis killing the builds is still unknown. It is pretty annoying that Travis seems to kill builds unpredictably, and without providing the reason. I am pretty sure we are not hitting any of the [disclosed limits](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/):

> Because it is very common to see test suites or before scripts to hang up, Travis CI has hard time limits. If a script or test suite takes longer to run, the job will be forcefully terminated and you will see a message about this in your build log.
>
> With our current timeouts, a job will be terminated if it's still running after 50 minutes (120 minutes on travis-ci.com), or if there hasn't been any log output in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The `Killed` message means you are out of memory. Check your limits by `ulimit -a` or available memory by `free -m`, then try to increase your stack size, e.g. `ulimit -s 82768` or even more.

Answer (score 0):

Had a fortran project exiting with

```
collect2: ld terminated with signal 9
```

on TravisCI, prob killed by out-of-memory.

Adding `sudo: required` to `.travis.yml` helped me out!

```
matrix:
    include:
        - os: linux
          sudo: required
```